# VS 2010 Beta 2 Install Error

Tags: visual-studio-2010

While installing VS 2010 beta 2, I got this error:

```
Error 1330: A file that is required cannot be installed because a cabinet file d:\cab13.cab has an invalid digital signature.  This may indicate a file is corrupt.
Action Failure: Action Ended : InstallFinalize. Return Value 3
... Install. Return Value 3
```

However, VS kept installing.  What repercussions does this have?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the specific reasons for the error was related to SQL express, so I won't have SQL express as a feature.  Not sure why it errored; there were a lot of permissions-related issues outside the cab file failing, but I can live without that working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Were you trying to install into a VM?  If so, you might check this blog post:

[How to workaround error 1330 during visual studio 2008-installation.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/heaths/archive/2007/12/14/how-to-workaround-error-1330-during-visual-studio-2008-installation.aspx)

It's for VS 2008, but it appears to be the same issue with VS2010 - basically, unpack the ISO to the VM Hard Disk, and install from there.

Comment: Thanks.  It is in a virtualized environment, I had the ISO on my hard disk, and had the virtual mount it...  I double-checked the error log and all of the errors seemed to be related to SQL Express, so I'm OK without that...